# kubernetes production deploy docker multi-node or ubuntu bare metal?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

We are currently trying out docker multi-node and need recommendations on production deployment docker or bare metal on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getting started guides using docker (both the single and multi-nodes examples) are not meant to be used in a production deployment. They are meant to provide the lowest friction path to getting a cluster running where you can experiment with the Kubernetes concepts in a running cluster.

If your choices are between running a variant of the docker multi-node configuration and bare metal on Ubuntu, I would definitely recommend running on Ubuntu. See the [Kubernetes Deployment On Bare-metal Ubuntu Nodes](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu.html) getting started guide.

Comment: That guide doesn't seem to exist anymore (not at that URL anyway)

Comment: The doc website keeps getting reshuffled. I think that the new version of that link is now https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/.